# How to enable vsync in 2D in Win XP and Win7?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I wonder how to enable vsync in WinXP and Win7 without compositing on. For example, make the windows to drag smoothly without tearing.

I am not interested in

- Enabling vsync in 3D applications, including 3D composed desktop
- Enabling vsync in media players

I have seen some sites in the internet, claiming that this is impossible, but ***I did it myself*** for Win XP several times, just forgot how I did it. So please do not answer this way please. Last time I used Windows was 2008. But by that time I already lost the recipe, I just used the system and thought that people who claim it is impossible should come here and see themselves.

The only thing I remember is that enabling vsync was not that difficult, it was just some registry hacking I found on the web, but currently I cannot find that website.

Comment: Riva Tuner , the 3rd party GPU tweaker is said to have a directx v-sync option available?  I wonder if that might be a source to find out more?  For me the clock rate of the gpu at the time effects how visable (fast) the glitching is.

Comment: @Psycogeek DirectX affects only 3D, sorry.

Comment: DX is a lot of software to the GPU stuff direct3d and DirectDraw DirectShow.  Other than games there is a lot of applying the DX in the winders system, all in 2D .  What I am trying to find is the V-sync  for the software to gpu stuff :-)  so that is ONE path to search in the bleak web info, to try and get 2D V-syncing turned on.

Comment: More fun stuff Some differances from XP to Vista and up  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/ff569520(v=vs.85).aspx (one location for v-sync stuff in registry) & http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/27/10405554.aspx#10405806  (snide info , missing some logic , but there)

Answer (score 1):

I may be very much wrong, because I do not remember now, but my current impression is that it can be enabled in the Nvidia Control Panel (along with 3D vsync, which is a separate setting), but only if the monitor is attached via D-Sub connector. In case of DVI the setting disappears. So one has to

- Have an Nvidia hardware
- Attach the monitor via D-Sub
- Possibly also have an older version of Nvidia Control Panel.